# 2nd-order ODE Solution for when Discriminant = 0

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

**My textbook says the following:**

Knowing $y(t)=ce^{rt}$ is a solution for $ay''+by'+cy=0$, we find for the case of $b^2-4ac=0$ that $r=\frac{-b}{2a}$. Therefore one particular solution is $y(t) = \exp\left(\frac{-b}{2a}t \right)$.

However, another linearly independent solution exists and that is $y(t)=t\exp\left(\frac{-b}{2a}t \right)$.

The derivation to find the second equation is that we can say $y(t)=ce^{rt}=v(t)\exp\left(\frac{-b}{2a}t \right)$ with variation of parameters, and then plug that $v(t)\exp\left(\frac{-b}{2a}t \right)$ into the equation (1)

$$ay''+by'+c=0 \tag{1}$$

we find that $v''(t) = 0$ and therefore v(t) is a linear function chosen to be $v(t)=t$. Hence the 2nd solution is $y(t)=te^{rt}$ and solution space is $y(t)=c_1e^{rt}+c_2te^{rt}$.

I have plugged $v(t)\exp\left(\frac{-b}{2a}t \right)$ many times into equation (1) yet can never seem to get the conclusion that $v''(t) = 0$. What does my textbook mean by this?

CITATION: *page 213, Differential Equations & Linear Algebra, Second Edition, by Farlow, Hall, McDill, West*

Comment: The discriminant of your differential equation is not zero $\Delta =1-4=-3$

Comment: @LostInSpace Could you elaborate? Once I did plug into the equation some a,b,c values that satisfied b^2-4ac=0 I ended up getting v"(t)-3v(t)=0. But, in this case I didn't use any numerical values, so how did you know that my discriminant is -3?

Comment: The polynomial characteristic of your differential equation is $r^2+r+1=0$ and the discriminant is not zero. Did you calculate it ? You should choose a DE with discriminant equal to zero  for example $y''-2y'+y=0$

Comment: @LostInSpace Is the characteristic equation not $ar^2+br+c=0 $ like in my equation (1)? I used that and didn't get v"(t)=0. I calculated twice choosing a,b,c appropriately to satisfy discriminant = 0.

Comment: For your differential equation the characteristic polynomial is $r^2+r+1=0$ the discriminant is $ \Delta = 1-4=-3$

Comment: @LostInSpace sorry. I realize you were pointing out a mistake I made. Now that I fixed it, it should satisfy my question right? But does this fix get the textbook answer that v"=0, because I don't see how to get that. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem Ebehr...did you calculate the derivative of the solution and plug it in your equation ?

Comment: @LostInSpace For this I tried using the case of b=4 and a,c =1. https://i.imgur.com/V3iomgb.jpg

Comment: @LostInSpace Oh noo... I realize it doesn't satisfy b^2-4ac=0. Please forgive me as I fix this careless oversight.

Comment: I did the calculation and get the answer 's book $v''=0$

Comment: @LostInSpace I just corrected my work and got the correct solution like you said. This discussion was incredibly helpful; thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcomed Ebehr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate first the derivatives 
$$y=ve^{-bt/2a}$$
$$y'=e^{-bt/2a}(v'-\dfrac {bv}{2a})$$
$$y''=e^{-bt/2a}(v''-\frac b a v'+\dfrac {b^2v}{4a^2})$$
Your equation becomes:
$$ay''+by'+c=0$$
$$av''+v(-\dfrac {b^2}{4a}+c)=0$$
Since
$$\Delta=b^2-4ac=0 \implies v''=0$$